# MySql, Foreign key for multiple columns of the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to define a foriegn key for name and ID that are from the same table animal.

```
CREATE TABLE vet_appointment(
name VARCHAR(15),
ID CHAR(9),
date_tome DATETIME,
ID_client CHAR(9),
ID_vet CHAR(9),
PRIMARY KEY (date_time),
FOREIGN KEY (name, ID) REFERENCES animal(name, ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_client) REFERENCES client(ID),
FOREIGN KEY (ID_vet) REFERENCES vet(ID));
```

This part of the code "FOREIGN KEY (name, ID) REFERENCES animal(name, ID)," is giving me this error "150 Foreign key is incorrectly formed". If I eliminate this foreign key the table is created. So I know this is the problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show us the create table animal too.

Comment: I don't think the problem is there, because when I use "FOREIGN KEY (name) REFERENCES animal(name), FOREIGN KEY (ID) REFERENCES animal(ID)" it works. I just don't want I really big code

Comment: Does the animal table have a (name, ID) key? (Primary key or unique constraint.) One id key and one name key is not the same as a (name, id) composite key.

Comment: The primary key of table Animals should be a composite key (name, ID).

Comment: The ID from animal is also a foreign key from another table. And name in animal is a primary key.

Comment: MySQL requires foreign keys to be indexed, hence the index on the referencing columns

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you really want this:

```
CREATE TABLE vet_appointment(
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    id_animal int,
    date_time DATETIME,
    ID_cliente CHAR(9),
    ID_vet CHAR(9),
    unique (date_time),
    FOREIGN KEY id_animal) REFERENCES animal(id),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_cliente) REFERENCES client(ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ID_vet) REFERENCES vet(ID)
);
```

The name of the animal should not be in this table.  It should be in the `animal` table.

I also recommend using auto-incremented integer primary keys for your table.  However, you may have a reason for preferring `char(9)` keys.

Comment: It's a homework, the teacher wants me to include the name of the animal in the table appointment

Comment: @KellyBaptista . . . Your teacher is wrong.  That sets up referential integrity problems.  You should be looking it up in the `animal` table (or `pets` table).  It is a shame that a course would be teaching bad data design.